# Python requests cant get source code on trip advisor

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape airline reviews on TripAdvisor, notably using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. However when I apply `BeautifulSoup` to the result of my request, I can't get the source code of the page. Rather, it seems that I get only some part of the source code. Is there some kind of protection? Is there a mistake I am missing in my code?

Here is my code:

```
#%% Libraries and other basic inputs
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
        #'User-Agent': '*',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8728987-Reviews-or25-Aeroflot#REVIEWS"
r = s.get(url,allow_redirects=False)

print(r.status_code) # I get status 200

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print('\n Body = ',soup.find(class_="location-review-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--gOmRC")) # Example trying to find the body of a review ; the element is actually in the source code but not in soup ; returns None
```

I have more than 2000 lines for both the source code and the content of `soup`, which is why I am not posting them here.

Comment: What is your current output? Do you get any HTML?

Comment: Well... None for `soup.find(...)`. And yes I do get some HTML.

Comment: There was one missing sentence: I only get part of the source code.

Comment: This website is using ReactJS and the data that you want is not present in the webpage but rather fetched dynamically from graphql, if you look into networks tab of your browsers developers tools you'll find graphql endpoint `https://www.tripadvisor.com/data/graphql/batched`, you can fetch data from this endpoint without bs4.

Comment: I get zero content also with a code that does get content from other websites. (I tried to put everything inside a list using find_all) result = empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is rendered using XMLHttpRequest (XHR) using JavaScript. Requests does not have the ability to use XHR as it does not have a JavaScript engine.
You can use Selenium or other technologies.
To use Selenium

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

Then get a driver e.g. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

the code is something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8728987-Reviews-or25-Aeroflot#REVIEWS"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()
for reviewTitleText in soup.find_all('a', {"class": re.compile("^location-review-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText")}):
    print(reviewTitleText.text)
```

Outputs:

```
Just don’t. And the airport sucks.
Nightmare for Transit flight
Interesting flight
Great flight experience -- Moscow airport understaffed and overworked
Comfortable trip for a business flight
```

If you are on windows you will have to supply the path to your drive in webdriver.Chrome()

Also I'm using a regular expression for the class name as these change with every page request.

Comment: Great, thank you ! I understand that the `time.sleep()` is also necessary to have things work. I'll see if I can reduce the waiting time.